# Accessing data from barcode scanner app to use in SQLite query

Tags: java, android, sqlite

This is my first question here on stack overflow, so please forgive me for any oversight or formatting errors. This issue seems simple enough, but I am not able to "put the pieces together" for some reason. I am also learning java and android studio as I go, so please forgive and educate on any bad code.

I need to gather data from my barcode scanning app, submit it to a variable, and then pass that variable through my database to fetch information based on the UPC code. I am using the ZXing library for the barcode scanner, with the handleResult method to capture the initial data.

I have the data collected within the SimpleScanner activity, but I can't figure out how to use that variable in a SQlite query. Below are the main classes I am using.

Any help would be appreciated. I can query the entire database just fine, but I need to look up the rows that match the actual item I am scanning. Thanks again!

**SimpleScannerActivity.java**

```
package com.example.android.dropr;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.zxing.Result;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import me.dm7.barcodescanner.zxing.ZXingScannerView;

public class SimpleScannerActivity extends MainActivity implements               ZXingScannerView.ResultHandler {

private ZXingScannerView mScannerView;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle state) {
    super.onCreate(state);
    mScannerView = new ZXingScannerView(this);  // Programmatically initialize the scanner view
    setContentView(mScannerView);               // Set the scanner view as the content view
}

@Override
public  void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    mScannerView.setResultHandler(this);    // Register ourselves as a handler for scan results.
    mScannerView.startCamera();             // Start camera on resume
}

@Override
public void onPause () {
    super.onPause();
    mScannerView.stopCamera();              // Stop the camera on pause
}


@Override
public void handleResult(Result rawResult) {
    String TAG = "Dropr";

    /**
     * Create Alert Dialog, so that user has time to read the information within.
     */

    AlertDialog.Builder scanInfo = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);


    String messageContent = "Content - " + rawResult.getText();
    String messageFormat = "Format - " + rawResult.getBarcodeFormat().toString() + ".";
    scanInfo.setTitle("Scan Information:");
    scanInfo.setMessage(messageContent + "\n" + messageFormat);
    scanInfo.setCancelable(true);

    scanInfo.setPositiveButton(
            "OK",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    dialog.cancel();
                    // IF you would like to resume scanning, call this method below:
                   // Handle the data
                    Handler handler = new Handler();
                    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            mScannerView.resumeCameraPreview(SimpleScannerActivity.this);
                        }
                    }, 1000);
                }
            });

    AlertDialog showInfo = scanInfo.create();
    showInfo.show();

    // Do something with the result here
    Log.v(TAG, rawResult.getText());
    Log.v(TAG, rawResult.getBarcodeFormat().toString());
  }
}
```

**DatabaseAccess.java**

```
package com.example.android.dropr;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class DatabaseAccess {
    private SQLiteOpenHelper openHelper;
    private SQLiteDatabase database;
    private static DatabaseAccess instance;
    private SimpleScannerActivity scannerActivity = new SimpleScannerActivity();    
/**
 * Private constructor to avoid object creation from outside classes.
 *
 * @param context
 */
protected DatabaseAccess(Context context) {
    this.openHelper = new DatabaseOpenHelper(context);
}

/**
 * Return a singleton instance of DatabaseAccess.
 *
 * @param context
 * @return the instance of DatabaseAccess
 */
public static DatabaseAccess getInstance(Context context) {
    if (instance == null) {
        instance = new DatabaseAccess(context);
    }
    return instance;
}

/**
 * Open the database connection
 */
public void open() {
    this.database = openHelper.getWritableDatabase();
}

/**
 * Close the database connection
 */
public void close() {
    if (database != null) {
        this.database.close();
    }
}

/**
 * Read all quotes from the database.
 *
 * @return a list of quotes
 */
public List<String> getCodes() {
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery("SELECT name, upc14 FROM Barcodes", null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
        list.add(cursor.getString(0));
        list.add(cursor.getString(1));
        cursor.moveToNext();
    }
    cursor.close();
    return list;
  }
}
```

Comment: Try to make it more clear (maybe by adding a section to your question) where and how exactly you have tried to create the sql query in your current code.

Comment: your first step should be to figure out how to write a select query with a where clause so that you can find the record with a barcode and then create a method with barcode parameter in your DatabaseAccess class (similar to getCodes, but returning an instance instead of a list).

Comment: I dont know if helpful, but in your method getCodes(), inside the while, you got "getStringget(0)" instead "getString(0)".

Comment: Thanks @JoséMª that was a formatting error, I am fixing it now!

Comment: @muratgu okay, I will work on figuring that out. I understand the basic MYSQL syntax, and my first thought was to create `"SELECT name, upc14 FROM barcodes WHERE some_variable = upc14"` some_variable being the raw data captured from the scan.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally came up with a solution, thanks to @muratgu! I created another method that creates and stores a variable for the scanned data, and passes the variable through a query.

```
/**
 * read a single record from the database the matches the UPC-A code scanned.
 * if there is no match, do nothing.
 * @param rawContent
 * @return a brand name based on the matching UPC-A code that was scanned.
 */
public String getInfo(String rawContent) {
    String TAG = "Getinfo():";
    String content = "00" + rawContent;
    String brandName = "";
    Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery("SELECT name, upc12 from Barcodes WHERE '" + content + "' = upc12", null);
    if(cursor.getCount() > 0) {
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        brandName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("name"));

        cursor.close();
    } else {
        Log.v(TAG, "uh oh, something went wrong in the if loop! ");
    }

    return brandName;
}
```

This method gets called in the SimpleScannerActivity.java file, where the scanned data can be passed through the variable. The method returns the name of the item, which is then placed in the dialog box. Exactly what I needed.

Thanks again, @muratgu! you gave me enough information that I could solve the problem myself. I just had to think on it for a bit!